# Null value in SQL Server 2005 table

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, null

I'm using a table `LOG` which has 3 columns:

- `Login nvarchar(50)`
- `Date int`
- `Logout nvarchar(50)`

Now if I don't enter a value into the `Logout` column, then `NULL` should be stored. But for me it is stored as `" "`.

I have given my table definition in screenshot 1 and the table data in screenshot 2.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is it default value?

Comment: can you send the insert query?

Comment: Are you sure that the DAL *isn't* inserting `" "` (or `""`)? Also, consider using *more appropriate data-types* for the columns (e.g DATETIME2 or DATETIMEOFFSET) - this will also "fix" the <br> issue, collect relevant information that is missing (the exact login/logout day), and allow sensible ordering. And I'm not even going to ask why the "Date" column is an (identity) PK column ..

Answer (score 0):

May be in the INSERT query you are using INSERT INTO log (Login, Date, Logout) VALUES(...) and a "" as the value for the Logout field. Check your insert statement and verify that you are not making this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

List of Alternative to solve this :

1. Set Default Value to that Column.
2. Provide NULL with out 'NULL' In Insert Query.
3. Select Data if '' found then NULL. (No change during insertion)
4. Update current data if '' found then set NULL.

Thanks.

Comment: The Actual scenario is If I forget to insert the value, then it have to be as **"NULL"**. For this I can use the default value. But I want to check whether the field is **NULL (or) NOT**. How can I check this...?

Comment: please see your application textbox , I think there is '' empty string put or please send me your insert query.

Comment: Sry @Anu, I doesn't insert the value. I will Update the table with the Logout time..... Cmd = new SqlCommand("update ActLog set Logout='" + TimeOut.Text + "' where Date='" + curoutdate + "'", Con);

Comment: would you please check your TimeOut.Text value. I think there is  problem.

Comment: Thnkx @Anu... for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Impdate.ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Logout", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Impdate;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Logout", SqlDbType.Date).Value = SqlDateTime.Null;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Impdate.ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Logout", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Impdate;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Logout", SqlDbType.Date).Value = "";
                }
```